# How to approximate trajectories and movement of two oppositely charged particles?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, charge

Imagine a single, stationary charged atomic ion, say a Lithium anion or cation (Li+ or Li-).  Now imagine another a single free, oppositely charged particle--perhaps an electron or Hydrogen ion (H+)--passing by the first stationary atomic ion at a "classical" non-relativistic speed.  For simplicity, imagine they are both in a vacuum and both in zero gravity and free from outside electrical noise or other forces.

What is a good equation to use to calculate the trajectories and/or movement of both of these particles, knowing the velocities and masses of each?

UPDATE:

While Ana V's answer below is very good, I'm really looking for an actual approximate answer of how close the two particles need to be to have measurable movement based on the forces. I'm not looking for a high level of accuracy.  Just trying to get a sense of the scale of impact on the trajectory of the moving particle and the movement (if any) of the stationary particle as you vary the closest distance between them.  Would they need to be very close to each other (say, less than a micron)?  Or would the stationary ion still exert enough force at macro-scale distances (say, a meter?) to measurably change the moving particle's trajectory and/or push away the stationary ion?  How close together do they need to be for the electrostatic forces to move one or both of them measurably?  Thank you!

Comment: Define "little"

Comment: Come on, really? Small can mean different things. Is small a deviation of Planck length or a nanometer?

Comment: Depends on the energy of the electron.

Comment: @CuriousOne in what way?  if the energy is higher, is the repulsive force higher or lower?

Comment: The force is the same, the momentum transfer will be smaller for a higher energy electron. You are basically looking at a Kepler problem if you are happy with the classical description of the motion.

Comment: Jimmy360:  Let's say a nanometer.

Comment: CuriousOne:  Is it Kepler (ie gravity?) or is it electrostatic force that is the greater force?

Comment: CuriousOne:  And since they are both negatively charged particles, the force is repulsive.  I don't think Kepler deals with repulsive forces?  also thought electrostatic force was much stronger than gravity.

Comment: he meant in the sense of  a classical solution of a 1/r potential, (in this case repulsive). To get numbers one has to solve equations. For distances commensurate to h_bar, one has to look at a specific momentum to get a distance x.  This has been done experimentally in positron proton scattering, with Q**2 and an angle either fixed and plotting the other. The answer is not one number but a plot.

Comment: Anna V:  My question is more about the range of the plot values in typical laboratory speeds of electrons shot out of an electron gun, not an exact plot or a specific number.  Let's say the electron is "slow moving," perhaps 2.18 x 10^6 m/s (as if it were in a Bohr orbit in the H atom).  What is the range of values of the plot?

Comment: What's a negatively charged atom?

Comment: So would that be a proton then? Or is it a heavier ion, because the answer depends on this too.

Comment: @RobJeffries For simplicity, let's say it's a Hydride anion H-

Answer (score 9):

This may help your, it comes from [Rutherford scattering](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/rutsca2.html) by  which they determined that the atom has a hard core. It is positive alphas against positive nucleus, but the math is the same.

[image: impact parameter]

> Determining the closest approach to the nucleus amounts to calculating the minimum distance for the hyperbolic orbit which is produced by the coulomb repulsive force. The expression for the closest approach as a function of the impact parameter b is given by:

[image: formula]Which has a limit for back-scattering which is just determined by setting the initial kinetic energy equal to the final potential energy. This corresponds to stopping the projectile and sending it backward, so at its closest approach, all the energy is in electric potential energy.[image: formula]

If you are truly interested enter the values in the calculating entries of the  link and get hard numbers.

**edit** after edit

One has to realize that the Coulomb potential goes to infinity and a unique number cannot be given for a quantity that has a functional dependence.  In this case the momentum and the angle of scattering have to be defined to determine r_min, which makes for a [complicated algebraically analysis](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/impar.html#c1) dependent on the specific masses and momenta involved .

Comment: Anna V: Thank you, perfect. This formula applies to the projectile, so I wonder if there is equal and opposite formula for the target? With Rutherford experiment, the target is fixed.  In mine, the target is free (like a Hydride gas, I suppose). With both the projectile particle and the target being free, assume the formula would also include the target and it's mass/momentum (it is stationary in my example).

Comment: Interestingly enough, Rutherford derived the scattering expected from a generic inverse square law. It applies equally well to repulsive or attractive forces, although the trajectories are of course different for the two. For example, the cross section and scattering angles for comets and the sun are described by the generic Rutherford formula. And, no, Rutherford's math does not 'fix' the nuclei - that is why the center of mass term is in there.

Comment: Jon Custer: Thank you.  What I mean by "fixing" the nuclei is that Rutherford was not interested in any movement of the target atoms -- in your astronomical example, how much the Sun is moved by the passing comet.  Guessing a comet cant move the sun much more than a He+ ion hitting gold atom?  But that is the 2nd part of my question--how do determine how much the stationary ion is moved by the passing particle.

Comment: you have to do a kinematic transformation. Define the ion initially at rest, laboratory frame,  and see the changes in time. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node52.html

Comment: @PurposeNation You can view this from the center of mass of both particles, such that the other particle will would trace the mirrored trajectory of the first particle but scaled by the mass ratio (such that the center of mass would not move).

Comment: @fibonatic. Thank you.  Yes, conceptually I undertsand the solution, but my calc skills are a little rusty and dont need the exact answer, just hoping for a rough idea of the impact