# What's the third equation that allows solving the closest approach of two electrons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrons, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics

Lately, I have been thinking about the following situation: in one-dimensional space, if we have two electrons, and one of them is stationary while the other approaches with some velocity, what would be the minimal distance between them, and their velocities at that moment? I'm just considering the most basic example where the particles are considered charged rigid bodies. As in this picture:

[image: an electron approaching another electron]

The energy and momentum of the system are conserved, and this is what we get when we apply the laws of conservation.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{mv_0^2}{2} &= \frac{mv_1^2}{2} + \frac{mv_2^2}{2} + \frac{kq^2}{l} \\
mv_0 &= mv_1 + mv_2
\end{align}$$
I have no idea where can I get a third equation in order to solve the system.

Comment: This is a standard scattering problem, and you can thank Rutherford for the solution more than 100 years ago.

Comment: What would be this solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to approximate trajectories and movement of two oppositely charged particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186726/)

Comment: No, in my case trajectories are not important because all of this happens on a single particular axis. Look at the update.

Comment: Classical with relativity or classical without relativity ?

Comment: Classical without relativity - the most simple example.

Comment: I suppose that energy and momentum are conserved but this is not enough to find the minimal distance between the electrons.

Comment: It's almost enough. Just think about what the relative momenta (or relative speeds) of the two electrons should be at distance of closest approach and then apply those conservation laws and you're basically there.

Comment: Well, I think that the relative velocities are zero when the distance between the electrons is minimal. What do you think of what I wrote in the update?

Comment: I think this should be solved using quantum mechanics since electrons are quantum mechanical objects.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I wanted just a simpler classical example. Therefore, we can just think of these particles as normal charged rigid bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact question on an exam once, translate to the center of mass frame and use conservation of energy, at the minimum distance both have zero kinetic energy in the CM frame.